# DB2 Copy via Load in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I am trying to copy data from Table_A to Table_B for given input parameter.

How can I use the value of *ID* in *Load cmd*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CP
(IN ID VARCHAR(10))
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC SQL220916104128256
BEGIN
call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(
'LOAD FROM (SELECT ''ID'', NAME, TYPE FROM TABLE_A) OF CURSOR INSERT INTO TABLE_B'
);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you need to provide the value of ID in your query, you are now providing the string 'ID':

```
'LOAD FROM (SELECT ''' || ID || ''', NAME, TYPE FROM TABLE_A) OF ...
```

Comment: I just try it but got an error like this
_[Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  "AAA" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.28.11_
_ID_ has in my context the value _AAA_

Comment: -206 means there is no column AAA in TABLE_A. Is it the value 'AAA' you would like to copy?

Comment: Perhaps you should reveal what TABLE_A and TABLE_B looks like, and an example of what you would like to copy

Comment: `ID` is of `VARCHAR` data type according to the SP definition, not `INT`. Must be: `'LOAD FROM (SELECT ''' || ID || ''', NAME, TYPE FROM TABLE_A) OF ...`.

Comment: yeah working now, THX!